# Generate excel from android listview

Tags: android, excel, listview

I am having one listview, I want to generate excel file of that listview and share it by mail. is it possible with android?

Comment: you need to use java excel library to generate excel sheet in android

Comment: you can add the data in the db and use http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-create-excel-file-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to download java excel jar, use below link

[Java Excel Jar Link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjxl2612jar.htm)

After downloaded jar , add in your build.gradle file,

```
 dependencies {
    compile files('libs/jxl-2.6.12.jar')
}
```

Now you can create excel file using jar, In Java class,

```
private void createExcelSheet()
{
    String Fnamexls="excelSheet"+System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".xls";
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/newfolder");
    directory.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(directory, Fnamexls);

    WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

    wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

    WritableWorkbook workbook;
    try {
        int a = 1;
        workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
        //workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);
        Label label = new Label(0, 2, "SECOND");
        Label label1 = new Label(0,1,"first");
        Label label0 = new Label(0,0,"HEADING");
        Label label3 = new Label(1,0,"Heading2");
        Label label4 = new Label(1,1,String.valueOf(a));
        try {
            sheet.addCell(label);
            sheet.addCell(label1);
            sheet.addCell(label0);
            sheet.addCell(label4);
            sheet.addCell(label3);
        } catch (RowsExceededException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (WriteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        workbook.write();
        try {
            workbook.close();
        } catch (WriteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //createExcel(excelSheet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```