# How to Convert List to Excel in android?

Tags: java, android, excel, android-studio, file

I took references from [Generate excel from android listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510418/generate-excel-from-android-listview) and planned to convert List data to excel sheet but the basic functioning of this is not working when clicked on button.

```
    public void generateXL(View view) throws IOException {
    String Fnamexls="excelSheet"+System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".xls";
    File fsd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"kmc";

    File dir = context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(!dir.isDirectory() || !dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    boolean b=dir.mkdir();

    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(b), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    File file = new File(dir, Fnamexls);

    WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
    wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

    WritableWorkbook workbook;

    try {
        int a = 1;
        workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
        //workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);
        Label label = new Label(0, 2, "SECOND");
        Label label1 = new Label(0,1,"first");
        Label label0 = new Label(0,0,"HEADING");
        Label label3 = new Label(1,0,"Heading2");
        Label label4 = new Label(1,1,String.valueOf(a));
        try {
            sheet.addCell(label);
            sheet.addCell(label1);
            sheet.addCell(label0);
            sheet.addCell(label4);
            sheet.addCell(label3);
        } catch (RowsExceededException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();


        } catch (WriteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();


        }


        workbook.write();
        try {
            workbook.close();
        } catch (WriteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //createExcel(excelSheet);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, dir.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}



                    }
```

into myexcel and get an excel sheet as output.

The code is not throwing exception but file is not getting created.

Comment: `directory.mkdirs();` Only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist yet. And if you call mkdir then check the return vale and stop if it returns false.

Comment: You have several catch blocks -which is good-  but you are not informing the user if there is a catch. Display a toast() to inform the user. Also you continue if there was a catch. You should stop then.

Comment: `public void generatePdf(View view)` Pdf? And where is this called? And when is the code in your other code block executed?

Comment: I am calling it when the button got clicked and I have updated the function name.

Comment: You have not changed mkdirs nor catch code. Nor did you react on those comments.

Comment: My code is not throwing any exceptions but the file is not getting created, I have made the changes.

Comment: Your mkdirs code is wrong. Please reread my first comment. You are calling it blindly. And dont name getFilesDir() sdCard as it is not.

Comment: I have done         if(!dir.isDirectory() || !dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdirs();
        } But there is no change in program

Comment: That code makes no sense as if it not a directory then it is a file and mkdirs will not change it to a directory then. Moreover you are not checking the return value of mkdir. Please read my first comment again and do only the things that i suggested and do all things that i suggested.

Comment: Yes it is giving false

Comment: Yes as you call it a second time without an exists(). You are doing nothing with the return value of mkdir. And you should call mkdir only once. You should stop/return then. Now you continue blindly. Also remove the isDirectory call as i did not suggest that. Read my first comment.

Comment: Can you give me an example of writing some code?

Comment: `Only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist yet. And if you call mkdir then check the return vale and stop if it returns false. ` says all. Or `if directory does not exist then create directory and if creation fails then return.` Just write that in Java.

Comment: if( !dir.exists())
        if(!dir.mkdirs()) return;